# Not Receiving $_GET Values from jQuery AJAX Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm writing a small function to get the URL of an image and save to locally to server.

Here's the AJAX call (confirmed it's sending the correct URL to "getimdbpic.php" with firebug)

```
$.get("getimdbpic.php", { posterURL: data.Poster, movieTitle: data.Title },
function(picData){
alert("Data Loaded: " + picData);
});
```

The problem I'm having is with my PHP.

```
$url = $_GET['posterURL'];
$title = $_GET['movieTitle'];
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

I simply can't get the values that are being passed. The file_put_contents throws an error stating that the "File name cannot be empty". (referring to $url being empty)

Edit: Fixed the casing, still not receiving values.

Comment: Well, I could see posterURL and posterUrl being mixed up (case-sensitivity) but I'm not sure why movieTitle isn't working.

Comment: @echeese Pretty sure that's the answer

Comment: Yip. MovieTitle probably is working, but the error is referring to the $url so it fails all round

Comment: To debug, var_dump($_GET) to see what is being passed to your script.

Comment: @Phil agree with you. that's probably it - the error message is indicative enough.

Comment: @soulkphp getting an empty array: array(0) { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest JQuery. I saw a very bizarre bug like regarding values not getting sent that was fixed by an upgrade.

***EDIT***: Might want to try a fallback to standard `$.ajax()` since `$.get()` is just a wrapper around it:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getimdbpic.php", 
  data: { posterURL: data.Poster, movieTitle: data.Title },
  type: 'GET', // this is default, but just in case
  success: function(picData){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + picData);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue, I was using a really old version of jQuery (1.3.2). Upgraded to the latest version and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be mixing up the case between `posterURL` in the Javascript, and `posterUrl` in the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in the casing here:

```
$url = $_GET['posterURL'];
```